# The Derivation of the Ito-Wentzell Formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Is there a good derivation of the Ito-Wentzell Formula which is a generalization of the Ito's Lemma?

Here are some unsatisfactory references to the Ito-Wentzell Formula:
http://mathema.tician.de/dl/academic/notes/spde/spde.pdf has a cursory mention and an ambiguity description of it.
http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/series/sfb-373-papers/2002-53/PDF/53.pdf cites it in apparently rigorous fashion but skimped on the derivation.
http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3038 looks promising but unfortunately is in Russian, which I do not read.

Comment: Could you please add the statement of the Ito-Wentzell Formula you are looking for?

Comment: @saz: I have added some references. These are very unsatisfactory ones.

Comment: @ hans : Even the Bank and Baum article is not very precise in the hypothesis what is a smooth family exactly ? The paper of Hiroshi Kuntia "Some extensions of Itô's formula" (available in the séminaire de probabilité XV  Lecture Noties in Mathematics ° 850, is rigorous in this regard, and proof can be found there. Another reference where the claim is stated in a clear way (but without proof but with reference) is the book of Yor, Chesnay, Jeanblanc "Mathematical methods for market finance". Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Thank you very much for the detailed references. I completely agree with your assessment of the references I listed. However, on first reading, I am a bit puzzled by the $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ representation in $I^{(n)}_2$ in the proof of Theorem 1.1 of Hiroshi Kunita's paper. I wonder why he does not use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ instead. I probably will understand it more after chewing on it a bit more.

Comment: @ Hans : If the proof is not too long why don't post it as an answer and make community wiki ? Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Will do later.

Comment: I am not clear how to prove $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\int_{{t_k}}^{{t_{k + 1}}} {f_s^j({M_{{t_k}}})dN_s^j} }  \to \int_0^t {f_s^j({M_s})dN_s^j} .$$  My idea is to let $$\widehat {f_s^j} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {f_s^j({M_{{t_k}}}){I_{[{t_k},{t_{k + 1}})}}(s)} $$ and prove $$E[\int_0^t {|\widehat {f_s^j} - f_s^j{|^2}ds} ] \to 0$$. In this way, we need $$\left| {\frac{{\partial {f_s}({M_s})}}{{\partial x}}} \right| < K.$$  Any other way to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: @Aborna: Could you please specify which reference your first equation comes from?

Comment: from Kunita's paper, "some extensions of Ito's formulas". page 120, in one-dimensional case.